# Integration on unknown variable

Tags: r

I would like to code something like this on R :

```
 \int_{t_{r-1}}^y  \left\{ \int_{t_{r-1}}^{\tau} w(z+x) q(\tau-x\mid z+x)dx\right\} \times  g_i(y-\tau \mid z+\tau) d\tau
```

[image]

So I try to do this :

```
library(cubature)
f <- function(x){ W(Z+x[1])*h(x[2]-x[1],Z+x[1])*g_i(y-x[2],Z+x[2])}
adaptIntegrate(f, lowerLimit=c(t_r-1,t_r-1), upperLimit=c(x[2],y), y=y, Z=Z)
```

But R says to me that :

```
object 'x' not found.
```

How could I do?

Thanks!

Comment: Your example is not reproducible. What is `t_r*`?

Comment: I believe you need to define `x` as a value, and sans that the upperLimitupperLimit fails.  `x` in your limit can't be the same as the arbitrary `x` of integration in your function definition.  I'm not sure but I fear that you're trying to perform an analytic integral over τtau followed by a numerical integral, which this package cannnot do.

Comment: I can't define x because I don't know what is it. I just want to integrate on x and after on tau but I'm affraid that it's not possible on R to do this

Comment: It's not t_r it's (t_r-1)

Comment: You are missing the point: you can't do a numerical integral on a dummy variable (tau).  This is true in any language, not just `R` . You will need a computer algebra system to calculate the first integral, then you can do a numerical integral (assuming you have values for `y` and `tr-1`

Comment: yes I have values of y and t_{r-1}. I don't understand how to do for the first integral, can you tell me more? or give me an example?